# Server side actionscript: server to server stream republish with authentication

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-media-server

I am trying to send a live stream from FMLE to a CDN, but passing through our FMS (installed locally); so the chain I have is:

FMLE => FMS => CDN

Now, publishing to the **CDN is username/password protected**. If I try to connect directly **from FMLE to the CDN**, FMLE opens a layer asking for credentials to "Connect to FMS" - I fill the form with username and password provided by the CDN, click on OK, and **everithing works fine**.

**The problem** comes when **introducing the FMS**: I created a simple application in FMS to republish the stream (*simplified code below*), and it works fine for CDN that don't ask for username/password, but **I'm not able to figure out how to send credentials** from the FMS application to the CDN.

Here the code I'm using (it's simplified, I'm putting here only the core code):

```
application.onPublish = function (oClient, oStream)
{
    application.nc = new NetConnection ();  // Creating new NetConnection
    application.nc.connect (FMS_url);  // Connecting to CDN

    application.ns = new NetStream (application.nc);  // Creating new NetStream
    application.ns.setBufferTime (1);  // Setting buffer time
    application.ns.attach (oStream);  // Attaching incoming streaming
    application.ns.publish ("stream_name", "live");  // Publishing
}
```

More info:

- We do need to pass through FMS, so "why don't you stream directly to the CDN ?" is not an option :-)
- FMS URL and credentials are correct, it's not any typing error :-(
- After application.nc.connect(), the onStatus event is fired with NetConnection.Connect.Success, but inmediately after that it is fired again with NetConnection.Connect.Closed (without any other info).

Following suggestions found on the web, I tryed things like

```
application.nc.connect (FMS_url);
```

or

```
application.nc.connect (FMS_url + "?username&password");
```

or adding

```
application.nc.addHeader ("Credentials", false, { userid: "username", password: "password" });
```

... but nothing seems to work, the result is always the same.

Any suggestion ? :-) Thank you in advance, best regards

Comment: +1 for the very detailed question with everything that has been tried, much better then the other one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32442024/authentication-using-netconnection-actionscript)

Comment: I wrote this question first, but people tend to ignore long and detailed questions, so I wrote the other one to try catching answers :-)